# Receive filter mail once per week

Tags: feature-request, subscription

I'd like to receive filter mail only once per week.

The question asked is: 
Do you want email updates when new questions arrive in this filter?

Currently there are the options **15 minutes**, **3 hours** and **every day**. Unfortunately, I don't have the time to visit the sites that frequently, which means that the mails I receive are often deleted by me without ever reading them. I'd like to be kept in the loop though, so once a week would do fine.

Comment: Why does your email client delete old emails randomly?

Comment: Sorry, I delete them manually, when there are too many.

Comment: Then it's not our fault that you get missed notifications >:(

Comment: I have 2 filters, and every day I get 2 messages saying "New X questions for 31 June". I don't miss 'em, I just don't want 'em every day, that's all...

Comment: Receiving filter emails weekly seems perfectly reasonable regardless of what you do with the daily mails

Comment: Ah, thank you, thank you!